# How do you write factor operations for rule-based conditional probability distributions?

Tags: probability, predictive-models, conditional-probability, graphical-model, probabilistic-programming

Supposing I have rule-based conditional probability distributions (CPDs), $\{P(X|\text{Pa}_{X}), \cdots\}$, in a graphical model each represented as a set of rules $\mathscr{R}$ such that:

- For each rule $\rho \in \mathscr{R}$, we have that $Scope[\rho] \subseteq \{X\} \cup \text{Pa}_{X}.$
- For each assignment $(x,\textbf{u})$ to $\{X\} \cup \text{Pa}_{X}$, we have precisely one rule $\langle\textbf{c};p\rangle \in \mathscr{R}$ such that $\textbf{c}$ is compatible with $(x,\textbf{u})$. In this case, we say that $P(X = x | \text{Pa}_{X} = \textbf{u}) = p$.
- The resulting CPD $P(X|\textbf{U})$ is a legal CPD in that
  $$\sum_xP(x|\textbf{u}) = 1.$$ (Koller and Friedman, 2009).

How would I perform factor product and factor marginalize operations using this representation? I would appreciate a procedural description of this process or, even better, pseudocode.

Comment: What is "CPD"?  [Central Packaging Data](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=rule-based+cpd&hl=en&as_sdt=0&as_vis=1&oi=scholart)??  Current Pattern Display?  Collaborative Product Development systems?  Something else?  My best guess would be Conditional Probability Distributions, but please let us know specifically.

Comment: Conditional probability distribution, yes. I'll edit the post. Thanks!